# Buttons and image keeps disappearing

Tags: java, image, swing, button, slideshow

I have this piece of code:

```
public void polarprocesso() {

    JButton nxtb = new JButton();
    JButton bckb = new JButton();

    JFrame pola = new JFrame(" Processo de Polarização");
    pola.setResizable(false);
    JPanel bpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(700, 500));
    bpanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    pola.add(bpanel);

    nxtb.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FSIAP20132014.class.getResource("/Misc/next.png")));
    nxtb.setBounds(600, 430, 35, 27);

    bpanel.add(nxtb);
    nxtb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            contadorbt++;
            if (contadorbt > 3) {
                contadorbt = 3;
            }
            if (contadorbt == 0) {
                imagem.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FSIAP20132014.class.getResource("/Misc/polar2.gif")));
                imagem.setBounds(50, 170, 450, 300);
                textopola.setText(PolarTexto.texto1);
            } else if (contadorbt == 1) {
                textopola.setText(PolarTexto.texto2);
            } else if (contadorbt == 2) {
                textopola.setText(PolarTexto.texto3);
            } else if (contadorbt == 3) {
                textopola.setText(PolarTexto.texto4);
            }
        }
    });

    bckb.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FSIAP20132014.class.getResource("/Misc/back.png")));
    bckb.setBounds(550, 430, 35, 27);

    bpanel.add(bckb);

    textopola.setText(PolarTexto.texto1);
    imagem.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FSIAP20132014.class.getResource("/Misc/polar2.gif")));
    imagem.setBounds(50, 170, 450, 300);
    bckb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            contadorbt--;
            if (contadorbt < 0) {
                contadorbt = 0;
            }
            if (contadorbt == 0) {
                textopola.setText(PolarTexto.texto1);
                imagem.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FSIAP20132014.class.getResource("/Misc/polar2.gif")));
                imagem.setBounds(50, 170, 450, 300);

            } else if (contadorbt == 1) {
                textopola.setText(PolarTexto.texto2);
            } else if (contadorbt == 2) {
                textopola.setText(PolarTexto.texto3);
            } else if (contadorbt == 3) {
                textopola.setText(PolarTexto.texto4);
            }
        }
    });

    textopola.setEnabled(false);
    textopola.setBackground(Color.gray);
    textopola.setBounds(320, 10, 380, 170);
    textopola.setOpaque(true);
    bpanel.add(imagem);
    bpanel.add(textopola);

    pola.setResizable(false);
    pola.setSize(new Dimension(702, 500));
    pola.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    pola.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    pola.setVisible(true);

}
```

It basically enables me to have some sort of slideshow where he shows different text when the user pushes next and back button. However, as soon as i go to slide 2 all the button disappear and only appear if i hover the mouse on them. Images do the same, however they never appear back.

I don't know if i was clear enough

```
http://puu.sh/5DUaR
http://puu.sh/5DUbi
puu.sh/5DUbJ
puu.sh/5DUbY
```

Thank you all on advance

Comment: If you use a BorderLayout-Manager, you should use `bpanel.add(Component, {position constraint})` instead of just adding components. Have a look on the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a frame.revalidate() call.